# Plotting in Igraph - tkplot

Tags: r, igraph

Is it possible to save a tkplot as pdf?
What of adding a legend to it?

Below is the code that I have tried using; where after moving the vertices that overlapped and proceeding to use plot, I do not get a similar image as the one in tkplot which is clearer...

```
Coord <- tkplot(MGraph, vertex.size=3, vertex.label=NA, 
              edge.arrow.size=0.5, edge.color="black")
MCoords <- tkplot.getcoords(Coord)
plot(MGraph, layout=MCoords, vertex.size=5, 
             vertex.label=NA, edge.arrow.size=0.5, edge.color="black")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save your tkplot to eps format. For example:

```
g <- graph.ring(10)
idg <- tkplot(g)
tkp <- igraph:::.tkplot.get(idg)
tkpostscript(tkp$canvas, file = 'filename.eps')
```

Then you can convert it to a pdf, using some [eps2pdf](http://tex.aanhet.net/epspdf/#install) converter.

Comment: +1, but see also the `tkplot.getcoords()` functions, which queries the adjusted positions, and then you can use them in `plot()`. This is sometimes useful as `plot()` can more features than `tkplot()`, e.g. vertex shapes.